# why rangeslider is not kicking in?

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

I am trying to use the simple plugin rangeslider, but not sure why its not initializing even without any error in console. Plugin details can be found here
http://andreruffert.github.io/rangeslider.js/

here is the jsfildde: http://jsfiddle.net/aem2ngny/

Simple code:
**JQUERY and HTML**

```js
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" min="10" max="1000" step="10" value="300">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs when your browser already have native support for range inputs.

You can make it work by passing the option polyfill as false

```
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider({polyfill:false});
```

https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js/issues/150#issuecomment-103417880